# Is it good practice to use assert() in class mutators?

Tags: c++, assert

For example:

```
void Date::month(unsigned int inMonth) {
    assert(inMonth <= 12);
    _month = inMonth;
}
```

If this is not good practice, what is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use assert to ensure that an argument to a **public** member function is valid. The reason is that there's no way for clients of your class to react to a failed assertion in any meaningful way (the fact that asserts are removed from release builds does not help either).

As a rule of thumb, assert should only be used for things that are strictly under your control (e.g., an argument of a private method).

In this case you're better off throwing a [std::invalid_argument](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/invalid_argument/) exception:

```
void Date::month(unsigned int month) 
{
    if(month == 0 || month > 12)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("a month must be in the [1-12] range"); 
    }
    _month = month;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but an `assert()` in a public method might be better if `throw` leads to performance issues (think of `vector::operator[]`). But an `assert()` should **never** be used to validate external data, like input via file, socket, keyboard, etc. (At least not in production code)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

This is the right way.

Although I would call it `setMonth()` rather than `month()`

Also bare in mind that `assert()` is preprocessed into nothing in release builds. so if you want something that also works in release then either write your own assert or do a proper run-time check.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that also gives the code more readability would be defining an enumerated type for month:

```
enum e_Month {
   e_Month_January,
   e_Month_February, 
   e_Month_March, 
   // etc..
   e_Month_December
};
```

Now your assignment becomes:

```
void Date::month(e_Month inMonth) { _month = inMonth; }
```

Most compilers will cause an error for assigning another type to enum so you get compile time safety that it will always be in range.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, you can assert whenever it's unexpected input in your application.
In addition throw an exception something like ArgumentException in addition since you don't want to set an invalid month value.